# What is the format of writing and reading with RandomAcessFile

Tags: java, file, randomaccessfile

```
char[] input =new char[24];
        for (int i=0; i<24; i++){
            input[i] = (char)('a'+i);
        }
        RandomAccessFile bf = new RandomAccessFile("data1.txt", "rw");
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++){
            bf.writeChar(input[i]);
        }
```

With Above code, when I open the file, it seems to be "abcd..." as I expected, but when I try to read the file

```
RandomAccessFile rf1  = new RandomAccessFile("data1.txt", "r");
   rf1.seek(0);
   System.out.println(rf1.readChar());
   rf1.seek(1);
   System.out.println(rf1.readChar());

    rf1.close();
```

It gives 'a' as expected but when seek(1) it gives me ? rather than b, why?

Answer (score 1):

A char is 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes. You're reading from the middle of the first character, which results in an unmappable unicode character (which is translated to '?'). You want to do `seek(2)` instead.

From the javadoc for `public final void writeChar(int v)`:

> Writes a char to the file as a two-byte value, high byte first. The
>   write starts at the current position of the file pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Char is 1 byte.....Also, is there a function like sizeof in C such that I could not make such mistakes

Comment: It depends on the encoding. RandomAccessFile's writeChar() writes it as a 2 byte unicode character. Always pay attention to the encoding when reading and writing text.

Comment: @user3495562 To clarify: You should not be using `char` to read/write text from a file unless you *really* understand what that's doing. Character set encoding is important in modern software.

Comment: @BrianRoach hi, Then what should I do, say if I want to use filechannel to input an integer, how many bytes should I allocate?

Comment: If you're reading/writing binary data, it shouldn't be as bytes that map to a character set. Read/write it as 4 bytes (which is the size of an `int` in Java)

Answer (score 0):

`RandomAccessFile`'s `readChar` and `writeChar` methods reads/writes Unicode (2-byte) codepoint.

`seek` method positions file access pointer as offset in bytes, so `seek(1)` places read pointer on the second byte of Unicode "a" and following `readChar` retrieves a Unicode character constructed from low-byte of "a" and high-byte of "b"